# How to validate a modal form?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a custom module which adds a button to a node form. The button opens another node form in a modal and when submitted, it takes the entity created in the modal and fills in an entity ref field on the first node form:

```
function add_venue_form_node_master_events_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // only do this if from Modal
  if (!isset($_POST['_drupal_ajax'])) return;

  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_add_venue_ajax_submit';
  $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'use-ajax-submit';
}

function _add_venue_ajax_submit(array $form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
  // get NID of Venue we just created
  $nid = $form_state->getValue('nid');
  $node = Node::load($nid);
  $value = $node->getTitle() . ' (' . $nid . ')';

  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new CloseModalDialogCommand());
  $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#edit-field-vcr-cert-holder-name-0-target-id', 'val', [$value]));
  $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#edit-field-pcr-cert-holder-name-0-target-id', 'val', [$value]));
  $form_state->setResponse($response);
}
```

This works perfectly but the form doesn't validate (required fields that aren't filled in aren't highlighted in red and no message at the top of the modal to show errors).

I found wombatbuddy's response here: [Showing Form Validation Errors inside Modal](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2020-01-30/showing-form-validation-errors-inside#comment-13446631) showing how to do validation. This does work, but then my submit function doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to add validation into my existing code?

Comment: Do you know about the [Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser) module? It provides this functionality.

Comment: Interesting module. Turns out we already had it installed. Took a while to get it to do anything but seem to have it sort of working. Wouldn't fit well with the interface I am trying to create.

Comment: I found the answer here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232188/how-do-i-validate-form-elements-in-a-modal-without-closing